# Select distinct on 3 columns but return all columns

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

The following is a duplicate, because the trans code is the same.

I run this to remove such a dupe but its not doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM rklib.clspaytpa
ORDER BY otord#, otusrn, ottrnc
```

So that in the following we only want 1 'RRF' row, and the CWA row.

```
OTORD#  OTTRND  OTTRT   OTUSRN            OTTRNC
05582907    20150518    173805  MMOLINA RRF
05582907    20150518    173810  MMOLINA RRF
05582907    20150519    181515  MMOLINA CWA
```

Comment: Can you clarify and provide examples of what you want and don't want the output to be? It's not clear to me what you are trying to get.

Comment: Which RRF row are you interested in specifically? The OTUSRN values differ so the two rows aren't actually distinct.

Comment: just one of them, it can be the first one encountered.

Comment: So which fields need to be distinct and which are okay to collapse?

Comment: distinct is otord#, ottrnd, otusrn ( there are other fields that we want to include but they are not consideration for the distinct)

Comment: Please at least align the column data under the column headings; StilesCrisis implied th OTUSRN values are different, but seems probably instead [due to misaligned headings], that the values of OTTRT are different.?

Answer (score 2):

This would keep `otord#, ottrnd, otusrn` distinct and collapse `ottrt, ottrnc`:

```
SELECT otord#, ottrnd, otusrn, MIN(ottrt) AS ottrt, MIN(ottrnc) AS ottrnc
FROM rklib.clspaytpa
GROUP BY otord#, ottrnd, otusrn
```

Comment: THis is good MIke, just one thing, the col names do not carry when I run this for the ottrnd and ottrt it gives col name 0004 and 0005.